# "We are on strike today because of the moderator behavior. Please refrain from answering."

Tags: support, status-completed, suggested-edits

Someone suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7824979):

> We are on strike today because of the moderator behavior. Please refrain from answering.

Are more people seeing this, is it something serious, and... why!?

I don't think it's serious at all, but maybe someone with more superpowers should check it out.

Comment: WHAT? someone's not happy and trying to deface Stack? that won't end well...

Comment: I'm really just afraid I'm missing all the good stuff =)

Comment: Looks like someone flipped out.

Comment: It's not serious since no one in their right mind (except for robo reviewers) would approve those edits.  But even so, this user needs to take a chill pill.

Comment: "Comment: We are on strike because of the moderator Martijn Pieters behavior. Please refrain from answering today." - AHAHAHAHA Get out the popcorn.

Comment: @Mysticial wait... it's because of Martijn? I feel like there's a story there and I want to know it :p

Comment: I'm less concerned about them defacing this post, and more concerned about this "we".  Has this person, as a part of the collective, decided to protest in their name?

Comment: @Makoto While you may be right and it could be some kind of brigade, this may also just be a solo user who decided to start a strike and hoping others will follow?

Comment: Hrm.  It'd be a bit more concerning if there were more than one user that ultimately decided to do this.  As in, concerning that people would believe that this tactic would be viable on a site with as many eyes as Stack Overflow has.

Comment: @Makoto I haven't had the time for review queues for a little while, but I'm kicking up the edit one right now, and I can't seem to find anymore of these. I really think it's ONE user

Comment: I think so too.  I was being facetious with the "we" bit, anyhow. :P

Comment: "-305 16:19 reversal Voting corrected (learn more)" - Hmmmmm... Lemme guess, Martijn nuked a sockpuppet.

Comment: I rejected a handful of these - not enough to be a lot of users. I think it's a Royal we.

Comment: @Mysticial:  That *would* explain the interesting drop in reputation on their account...

Comment: "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 7 days."

Comment: So far for the show, I must say I'm disappointed.

Comment: @CamilStaps strike over!

Comment: I got the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7825015).

Comment: @SouravGhosh and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4487940/sigismundus?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) ;-)

Comment: We, the Stack Exchange moderators, are on strike today because of user behavior. Please refrain from burning the sites to the ground.

Comment: It's kind of funny how after a handful of them he opted to start using Martijn's name explicitly. Apparently he wasn't getting a desired effect.

Comment: Lol @martin welcome to the thunderdome! Sucker!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry. IMO, this "we" here <del>is</del> was [Nosism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism).

Looks like a [case of vengeance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4487940/sigismundus?tab=reputation).

The "case" has been handled. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4487940/sigismundus). Peace. :-)